# Why my Fiat Palio 1.6 2005 is overheating only after 5 min of drive?

Tags: cooling-system, overheating, head-gasket, thermostat

I have a Fiat Palio 2005 which I bought few days ago. I was driving it for last complete week and it was very smooth there was no problem at all. Yesterday , suddenly on a highway the temprature shooted up and my car engine stoped. I parked the car and waited for the engine to cool down after 30 min I opened the radiator cap and saw there was enough coolant and fan was also working perfectly. From yesterday my car is overheating within 5 min drive.

I have noticed one strange thing that is when I start the engine and turn the AC on, the temprature guage shoot to red line within 5-10 min but if I keep the radiator cap open the temprature guage never shoot up even for an hour.

Can someone explain is this a Head Gasket blown or a thermostat problem ?

Thanks,
Husnain

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Have you checked to ensure there's nothing clogging the radiator, like a plastic bag or something?

Answer (score 1):

Just Fixed it today it was a bad thermostat. Thermostat stuck in close state.